# vhdl synthesis optimization: counters in statemachines

Tags: fpga, vhdl, xilinx

I have a general question about the efficiency of a synthesizable state machine.

The first version uses the same counter for each state.
The second uses one own counter for each state.
Which version of the two is more efficient (logic area, speed...)??

How much area of the FPGA is occupied by the routing of the count1 signal when i use the same counter for each state.
Is it better to user one counter for each state??

I'hope somebody with more experience can explain which solution is the best (maybe a third version) and why.

Thank you!

Kind Regards,

Oliver

-- 1. Version ===============================================================

```
signal count1: integer range 0 to 1000 := 1000;  
type mystates is (s1, s2, s3, s4);  
signal mymode: mystates := s1;  

BEGIN  

MyProcess: process(clk)  

BEGIN  

    IF (clk'event and clk = '1') THEN  

        case mymode is  
        when s1 =>   
            If (count1 = 0) then  
            mymode <= s2;
            count1 <= 555;
            -- (stuff)
            else  
            count1 <= count1 - 1;  
            end if;  
        when s2 => 
            If (count1 = 0) then  
            mymode <= s3;
            count1 <= 666;
            -- (stuff)
            else  
            count1 <= count1 - 1;  
            end if; 
        when s3 => 
            If (count1 = 0) then  
            mymode <= s4;
            count1 <= 784;
            -- (stuff)
            else  
            count1 <= count1 - 1;  
            end if; 
        when s4 =>  
            If (count1 = 0) then  
            mymode <= s1;
            count1 <= 1000;
            -- (stuff)
            else  
            count1 <= count1 - 1;  
            end if; 
        when others =>  
            Null;  
        end case;  

    END IF;

end process;
```

-- 2. Version ===============================================================

```
signal count1, count2, count3, count4: integer range 0 to 1000 := 1000;  
type mystates is (s1, s2, s3, s4);  
signal mymode: mystates := s1;  

BEGIN  

MyProcess: process(clk)  

BEGIN  

    IF (clk'event and clk = '1') THEN  

        case mymode is  
        when s1 =>   
            If (count1 = 0) then  
            mymode <= s2;
            count1 <= 555;
            -- (stuff)
            else  
            count1 <= count1 - 1;  
            end if;  
        when s2 => 
            If (count2 = 0) then  
            mymode <= s3;
            count2 <= 666;
            -- (stuff)
            else  
            count2 <= count2 - 1;  
            end if; 
        when s3 => 
            If (count3 = 0) then  
            mymode <= s4;
            count3 <= 784;
            -- (stuff)
            else  
            count3 <= count3 - 1;  
            end if; 
        when s4 =>  
            If (count4 = 0) then  
            mymode <= s1;
            count4 <= 1000;
            -- (stuff)
            else  
            count4 <= count4 - 1;  
            end if; 
        when others =>  
            Null;  
        end case;  

    END IF;

end process;
```

Answer (score 7):

The first version is going to be more efficient in terms of area and speed-- but neither one is very good, IMHO.

A very quick way to estimate the size/speed of something is to think about each output signal and how many inputs the output is derived from.  For example:  a <= b xor c.  We say that 'a' is a function of 2 signals (b and c).  The more "inputs" there are, the more logic is required and the slower it will run.  Keep in mind that this is a super rough estimate, but is useful for, well, making super rough estimates.

In version 1, you have your mymode "output" which is a function of many inputs.  The important input is count1, which is a 10-bit signal.  So, without considering the other signals, you can say that mymode is at least a function of 10 inputs.  On the other hand, version 2 has 4 count inputs (each 10 bits), so it is a function of at least 40 inputs.  That's a lot of inputs, and will create a lot of logic that runs slow.

Now, here's a super easy way to make the logic for both versions smaller and faster.  For this example, I'm just going to do a simple counter that "does something" when it finishes it's count.  You can adapt the same techniques to your state machine.  First, here's your version:

```
signal count :integer range 0 to 1000;  

process (clk)
begin
  if rising_edge(clk) then
    if load='1' then
      count <= some_constant_value;
    elsif count=0 then  -- This line is important
      do something here;
    else
      count <= count - 1;
    end if;
  end if;
end process;
```

And here is my version:

```
signal count :std_logic_vector (10 downto 0);  -- Note:  1 extra bit

process (clk)
begin
  if rising_edge(clk) then
    if load='1' then
      count <= some_constant_value - 1;
    elsif count(count'high)='1' then  -- This line is important
      do_something_here;
    else
      count <= count - 1;
    end if;
  end if;
end process;
```

Your version counts from N downto 0, while mine counts from N-1 downto -1.  To make this work, I made the count signal 1 bit larger and also a SLV instead of an integer.  But where this really makes things faster is that your version is doing an N-bit comparison where mine is just checking a single bit.  In essence, I am using the carry-chain logic from the line "count <= count - 1" to also do my comparison.  The carry-chain logic is already there for the counter, I'm just making it one bit longer.  Since the carry-chain logic is super fast in an FPGA, and you're already using it, the resulting logic is super small and super fast.

For our 10 bit counter, the line "elsif count=0 then" would require three 4-input LUTs and 2 levels of logic in a Xilinx Spartan-3.  My version requires 1 Flip-Flop (and associated carry-chain that would have otherwise gone unused) and essentially 0 levels of logic.

But let's say that the counter was 32 bits.  Your version would require 11 LUTs and 3 levels of logic.  Mine would stay the same at 1 FF and 0 levels.

When you apply my method to the two versions of your state machine, each version will work.  Version 1 is still the better approach, but in some circumstances you can't have a single counter and so you must use Version 2.  With my method, instead of having a function of at least 40 inputs, you have a function of at least 4 inputs.  4 is much better than 40!

Comment: Nice trick. A very high speed way to do counters if the range is small enough is to simply encode the counter in shift registers. A counter from 0 to 7 would be "00000001". After one step, it's "00000010", etc. Check for COUNTER(COUNTER'high) = '1' as a done signal. The state machine is only as fast as the longest path...

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you [don't need the "others" clause](http://www.sigasi.com/content/can-you-do-without-others) in this case, as you have covered all the possible cases (from the point of view of the language).

Next, you have stripped so much from your code that neither state machine will do any real work. But if I had to guess, the two versions you write would have different behavior: One has a counter for each state, and the other has a global counter. One will use more logic and more registers than the other.

If you don't need to store the intermediate counter results, I suggest you only use one count register.

Finally, if you *really* want to know, **try both** and **look at the synthesis results**. That information is much more reliable than anything we can write on this forum.

Comment: thank you for your "answer". I just want to know which sollution is recommended.

Comment: @Philippe  While you don't "need" the others clause, you want the others clause.  Many simulators will complain if you don't have it, and many synthesizers will simply ignore it.  But...  Xilinx (and I'm sure other synthesizers) have a way to implement a 'safe' state machine.  In this case, when the state machine goes into an undefined state is executes the "when others" clause to recover.  This isn't always required, but is important when you might be glitching the clock on start-up (while initializing PLL's, or muxing clocks around).  It is good practice to always use "others".

Comment: @David not correct! You need the others clause _only_ if you have _not_ enumerated all the options. If you did in face cover all the options, the others clause is meaningless. Please follow the link and read the blog post.

Comment: @Philippe  I did read your link before posting my 1st comment.  There are many cases when you cannot possibly cover all enumerated states.  For example, if you are using one-hot encoding and, due to a glitch, the state variable goes to "1001"-- which is invalid in one-hot.  If you are designing a "safe state-machine" then you MUST have a mechanism to return to a valid state.  Some synthesizers (Xilinx and Altera used to do this) by using the Others clause.  Xilinx appears to have replaced it with the SAFE_IMPLEMENTATION constraint.  Other tools might still do it right (with others).

Comment: @David The Altera "safe state machine" jumps to the reset state, not to anything you write in the default clause. I have just tried it. 
I'd be surprised (but I'm willing to stand corrected) if Xilinx uses the state defined in "others". Do you have Xilinx documentation or an experiment to convince me?

Comment: @Philippe That's what Xilinx does now too. Hence my comment of "used to" and "others might still do it right". Even so, ill still do others if only to keep the simulator happy.

Comment: @Philippe  Precision Synthesis, from Mentor Graphics, uses the others clause for implementing safe state machines.  Check out the bottom of page 210 in this PDF:  http://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece412/references/precision/precisionRTL_style.pdf  This is the correct way to do it, IMHO.

Comment: Hi @David. Thanks for your pointer. I appreciate you taking the time to find the documentation that supports your point. I will make an addition to my blog post.